# JSON Web Token (JWT) - one account multiple users

Tags: authentication, jwt

If I'm using JWT to authenticate users to get access to my API, would it be possible to create one "generic" account for many users to use? That way, users who don't have a "real" account, would be given this generic account credentials in order to access the API. Would that be possible? Because, I'm wondering, with JWT, if one users log in, would I invalidate the other user token?

If that approach would not work, what would you recommend?

The reason: I want my app to communicate with my server, even if the user doesn't have an account created. But I would not like to keep that "door" open, hence I would like to add some kind of authentication for those people who are using the app but don't have an account. Suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing automatic that revokes a token if someone else logs in with the same account. In fact, it's even hard to do since multiple sites may have accepted it and need to know the token is invalid. The software you use to generate and/or validate the token may do it for you, but it's not likely it'll do it without explicitly saying so in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Create accounts connected with accountgroups. This way you are also able to create temporary accounts having less permissions for example. And multiple clients are able to access same data and same time.

So the Payload is owned by the accountgroup, the client authenticates with a (maybe temporary) account and gets authorization via accountgroup.